# Implode Inside For Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to implode the multi array inside the for loop.

```
$_POST['PprodName'];
```

In this `$_POST['PprodName']` I have got a value as:

```
Array ( [0] => steel mj23 [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => )
```

`steel mj23` is my first product name.

Now I want to check if the element is empty according to their position. so I applied a for loop but don't know how to implode element's which are not empty.

I want to implode only those element which are not empty.

Here is my for loop.

```
for( $i=0; $i < count($_POST['PprodName']); $i++ ) {
                    if( !empty( $_POST['PprodName'][$i] ) ) {
                        print_r($_POST['PprodName'][$i]);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a for loop. Simply filter all empty values with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) out and then you can simply use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), like this:

```
echo implode(", ", array_filter($_POST['PprodName']));
```

Comment: @WaseemAhmed No <- see the check mark to the left of my post. If you click on on this one you say that the answer solved your problem

Comment: @WaseemAhmed no ^ See my link above in the comments!

Comment: @Rizier123 but it says " Vote-Up requires 15 reputation "

Answer (score 0):

try this way
[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/FjnOfv)

```
$data=Array ( 0 => "steel mj23", 1 =>'test' ,2 =>'', 3 =>'' ,4 =>"", 5 =>"", 6 =>"", 7 =>"" );
$result=Array();
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
    if(!empty($value))
       $result[]=$value;         
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: it also works fine bro. but i think the array_fileter() is the father of all problem( Checking empty array )

Comment: @WaseemAhmed You think array_filter() is better, but accept this answer?! You know that you can only accept one answer?!

Comment: @ Rizier123 ok. undo and done. sorry. i am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
    $array = array(
        'fruit1' => 'apple',
        'fruit2' => 'orange',
        'fruit3' => ' ',
        'fruit4' => ' ',
        'fruit5' => 'apple');

        for ($i = 0; $i <  count($array); $i++) {
        $key=key($array);
        $val=$array[$key];
        if ($val<> ' ') {
           echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
           }
         next($array);
        }


     /* fruit1 = apple
    fruit2 = orange
    fruit5 = apple
    */
    ?>
```